# How to store a method and call it to the reusable methods file?

Tags: javascript, methods, cypress, var

How to store this select dob date picker method and call it and reuse it in this command file? It doesn't look right by writing the method directly in the command file.

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('editIndividualCustDetails',() =>

    {

       var editIndividualCustDetails =new editIndividualCustomerPage() 
    //click edit profile button
    editIndividualCustDetails.editProfileButton().click()
    
   //select DOB
    cy.get('#dob').invoke('val').then((text) => {
       expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
    });

    //enter Attention field
    editIndividualCustDetails.attention().type('CDEF')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create any file and write cypress custom commands under it, if you import the file under `cypress/support/index.js`.

Considering if you have a file at `cypress/support/utils/reusableMethods.js`

1.Import the file under `cypress/support/index.js` as:

```
import './utils/reusableMethods';
```

2.Write your custom commands normally under `cypress/support/utils/reusableMethods.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('editIndividualCustDetails', () => {
    var editIndividualCustDetails = new editIndividualCustomerPage()
    //click edit profile button
    editIndividualCustDetails.editProfileButton().click()
    //select DOB
    cy.get('#dob').invoke('val').then((text) => {
        expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
    });
    //enter Attention field
    editIndividualCustDetails.attention().type('CDEF')
})
```

3.Use it in your tests normally as :

```
cy.editIndividualCustDetails()
```